# Android - scrolling and flinging a dialog (DialogFragment)

Tags: android, gestures

I have a use case I need help with for an app I'm developing for special needs individuals. In one particular use case, when a video is selected from a thumbnail image in a listview element, the app pops up a dialog (using a DialogFragment) that contains a VideoView to play the video and a close icon. That's working as expected.

However, I'd like the popup dialog to have two touch behaviors: scroll and fling. The more important behavior of these is fling. So, I'd like the user to be able to move the dialog around and if a fling is detected, I dismiss the dialog.

I have both of these events detected, but I'm having trouble with the drawing (animation?) of the event.

I'm currently only dismissing the dialog when a fling is detected (i.e. no animation yet):

```
    final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                private PointF origin = new PointF();

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    origin.x = e.getRawX();
                    origin.y = e.getRawY();
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                        float velocityY) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onFling has been called!");
                    final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
                    final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
                    final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
                    try {
                        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                            return false;
                        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Right to Left");
                        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Left to Right");
                        }
                        dismiss();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // nothing
                    }
                    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                }
            });
```

However, I have attempted animation for scroll events and it's horrible. It flickers, jumps and duplicates.

```
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gesture.onTouchEvent(event);

            final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
                final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, pointerIndex);
                final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, pointerIndex);

                // Remember where we started (for dragging)
                lastTouchX = x;
                lastTouchY = y;
                // Save the ID of this pointer (for dragging)
                activePointerID = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, 0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its
                // position
                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(event,
                        activePointerID);

                final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, pointerIndex);
                final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, pointerIndex);

                // Calculate the distance moved
                final float dx = x - lastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - lastTouchY;

                posX += dx;
                posY += dy;

                moveWindow((int) posX, (int)posY);

                // Remember this touch position for the next move event
                lastTouchX = x;
                lastTouchY = y;

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                activePointerID = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                activePointerID = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {

                final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(event);
                final int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, pointerIndex);

                if (pointerId == activePointerID) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    lastTouchX = MotionEventCompat.getX(event, newPointerIndex);
                    lastTouchY = MotionEventCompat.getY(event, newPointerIndex);
                    activePointerID = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(event, newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void moveWindow(int x, int y) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
    layoutParams.x = x;
    layoutParams.y = y;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
}
```

I have done a a fair amount of research before posting this question and I am aware that I should probably be using an OverScroller and Animation somehow, but I can't figure out how to use these in my use case.

A note on Fling: For my fling, I simply want the exact same user experience as when you close an app by flinging it to the right in the Android task (app) view.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: instead of Dialog use PopupWindow - its better designed for things like that

Comment: Actually, I did try using a PopupWindow at first. However, I could not get the video to play using a PopupWindow. From the research I did it looks like there is an issue with Surfaces and PopupWindow. But thank you for the comment!

Comment: @pskink, are you familiar at all with playing video in a PopupWindow?

Comment: if its not working at you,  did you try some similar questions like: http://www.google.com/search?q=PopupWindow+videoview+stackoverflow&btnG=&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new&gws_rd=cr ?

Comment: also did you try TextureView instead of VideoView?

Comment: TextureView docs say: "Unlike SurfaceView, TextureView does not create a separate window but behaves as a regular View. This key difference allows a TextureView to be **moved, transformed, animated, etc**" so it for sure will work

Comment: your problem puzzled me a bit: here is a VideoPopupWindow implementation http://pastebin.com/Z9XGbKyE

Comment: @pskink - Thank you so much. You have clearly gone above and beyond for me. I am at work, so I can't really look at this stuff, but I will. Please advise how I can give you formal Stackoverflow credit.

Comment: the credit will be if you work out the right and elegant onFling implementation and publish somewhere since mine is broken...